# Extending a Vaadin Grid to a custom component?

Tags: vaadin, web-component

I have a custom component class for the Vaadin Grid:
import { Grid, GridColumn } from '@vaadin/grid';

@customElement('test-vaadin-grid')
export class TestVaadinGrid extends Grid {}

@customElement('test-vaadin-grid-column')
export class TestVaadinGridColumn extends GridColumn {}

However the cell content for each table cell is blank for:

```
    <test-vaadin-grid .items="${items}">
         <test-vaadin-grid-column path="firstName"></test-vaadin-grid-column>
         <test-vaadin-grid-column path="lastName"></test-vaadin-grid-column>
         <test-vaadin-grid-column path="email"></test-vaadin-grid-column>
         <test-vaadin-grid-column path="profession"></test-vaadin-grid-column>
    </test-vaadin-grid>;
```

If you replace test-vaadin-grid with vaadin-grid then the cells are populated, why is this the case?
I was expecting the table cells to be correctly populated with test-vaadin-grid.

Comment: Contact Vaadin, ask if they have hard-coded their tag-names

Comment: The first column has the wrong closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in `vaadin-grid-column.js`, [you can see that it's expecting the parent grid element to follow a specific naming pattern](https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/blob/main/packages/grid/src/vaadin-grid-column.js#L303-L311):

```
    _findHostGrid() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias, consistent-this
      let el = this;
      // Custom elements extending grid must have a specific localName
      while (el && !/^vaadin.*grid(-pro)?$/u.test(el.localName)) {
        el = el.assignedSlot ? el.assignedSlot.parentNode : el.parentNode;
      }
      return el || undefined;
    }
```